# How to mount Windows folders in WSL automatically on startup

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I go into WSL the `C` drive is automatically mounted at `/mnt/c`. I would further like to mount a folder `C:\D` to the mount point `/mnt/d`.

The contents of `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
/mnt/c/D        /mnt/d  none    bind
```

The contents of `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
# Enable extra metadata options by default
[automount]
enabled = true
root = /mnt/
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
mountFsTab = true

# Enable DNS – even though these are turned on by default, we’ll specify here just to be explicit.
[network]
generateHosts = true
generateResolvConf = true
```

When I do `sudo mount -a` then it mounts correctly. However it is not mounted at startup and running `mount -a` reports "mount: only root can use "--all" option".

Comment: Mounting is for _file systems_, I don't think you can "mount" a folder. You might be looking for a symlink: `ln -s /mnt/c/D /mnt/d`. However I'd not recommend this because you create the impression that it's a mount point while it's not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question is old but if somebody still hit the question I found the answer in [WSL release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17093)

> WSL now processes the /etc/fstab file during instance start [GH 2636].
> This is done **prior** to automatically mounting DrvFs drives; any drives
> that were already mounted by fstab will not be remounted
> automatically, allowing you to change the mount point for specific
> drives.

Therefore before bind mount one have to add mount for windows drive:
eg:

```
# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
C: /mnt/c drvfs rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off,umask=0027,fmask=0137, 0 0
/mnt/c/directory/for/mount /where/to/mount none bind,default 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convenient mount command to make your Windows home also your WSL home, provided you create the Linux user in the same name as your Windows account:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs C:/Users /home -o "rw,noatime,dirsync,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio"
ls -l ~/
```

The equivalent line to add to /etc/fstab to make it permanent and load your .bash_profile and .bashrc files in your Windows home folder is:

```
C:/Users /home drvfs rw,noatime,dirsync,mmap,access=client,msize=262144,trans=virtio
```

Voilà, enjoy!